# How to remove a list of elements from a list (F#)

Tags: list, f#

Is there a better way of doing removing a list of elements from another list?
So far I've been doing this, but its not efficient for larger lists

```
let values, valuesToRemove = [ for i in 0..10 -> i ], [ 0; 1; ]
let newValues = values
                |> List.filter ((<>) valuesToRemove.[0])
                |> List.filter ((<>) valuesToRemove.[1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `List.contains` here, e.g.:

```
let values, valuesToRemove = [ for i in 0..10 -> i ], [ 0; 1; ]
let newValues = values
                |> List.filter (fun x -> not (List.contains x valuesToRemove))
```